# How can we properly use nested onClickListener in my conditions?

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

In my code I have a nested onClickListerner:

```
but1.onClickListener.........{

    but2.onClickListener.........{
      Content (A)
    }

}

but2.onClickListener.........{

      Content (B)
}
```

But, when I click on but1 and then but2 i can access Content(A). But  when I tried to access Content(B) with click of but2 again, it access only Content(A).
How can I get Content(B) access with click of but2 , after successive clicking of but1 and but2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnClickListener's are assigned to View objects, and get called upon clicking the button. There can only be one assigned to the View at a time.
So the nested button2 OnClickListener has no knowledge of anything related to button1 being pressed first. You changed the OnClickListener after pressing button1, so you could change it back after button2 is pressed, but this seems like a bad code practice of constantly switching OnClickListener's.

Since the button can only have one OnClickListener at a time that is called, you might want to create one single OnClickListener for button2 to handle button2 being clicked, and then have a variable to keep track of the state of your button 1 being pressed first or not.